# android-how to prevent screen from turning on in this case?

Tags: java, android

each time the screen turns off, a `Service` in my app starts an `Activity`. the `Activity` overrides `onKeyDown` method for volume down and up keys. now the problem is when I press those buttons (and the screen is off) the screen turns on and I don't want this. how to prevent the screen from turning on and still receive key presses?

Comment: @Geobits that question has not received a working answer :(

Comment: Working? Maybe not, but the accepted answer is basically "Different phones act different ways, so counting on consistent behavior isn't a good idea". Seems just as applicable here, since this behavior is controlled by the manufacturer, and no one answer will fit all devices.